# Получение координат метки в событии Я.Карт

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Как получить изначально заданные координаты метке?

```
objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
 var coords = e.get('coordPosition'); // это не подходит,это координаты клика
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var coord = objectManager.objects.getById(e.get('objectId')).geometry.coordinates;`